# read.table or read.csv cannot load its data

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I'm in trouble with importing csv data to R.
csv is large scale of log data which has 50culumns and few million lines
including header.
I have 15 files and load some of them make issue.

```
data<-read.table("1.csv",header=T,sep=',', stringsAsFactors = F, fill = T)
```

After that code, in usual 1.csv loaded to 'data' or give warning if 1.csv has problem. But in my case, nothing happen.
After loading, there are no message and there is no object named 'data'.

is anyone experienced like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :

```
library(data.table)
fread('1.csv', header = T, sep = ',')
```

It's more efficient than `read.table` and maybe this is the main problem

Comment: If You can please make my answer as accepted.  Thanks